# TeX templates for mathematical articles

Tags: formatting, templates

I'm currently trying to write an article on a method of finding infinite series for some known functions. However, I'm finding it very difficult to:

1. Get a good guidance on how to structure the document. (I guess this is rather a question for math.SE)
2. Formatting the LaTeX to get the document done. This is why I'd enjoy getting a pre formatted file (like a template) for simple undergraduate articles to get a feeling of how they should be.

I've found this [link](http://www.ams.org/notices/200711/tx071101507p.pdf) but it states "This article is the third in an occasional series
intended for graduate students.", which explains why it's a little bit too long (or is it?).

I'm mostly stuck because I know very little about Latex and my formatting is poor.

Anyways, my main concern now points 1. and 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than looking for a template that meets your needs (which are quite general), I'd suggest reading some of the free documentation that you can get from [ctan](http://www.ctan.org). The [Not so short introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english) and the [amsmath package manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) will probably be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The article you link to is about creating articles that get published in "peer reviewed math journals". Your question (part 2) says you want a template for "simple undergraduate articles". That doesn't sound like you're looking for something that goes into a math journal. You can find a sample tex file for a math article (Mathematics Magazine) [here](http://www.maa.org/pubs/mmartic.tex). If you meant an article more like a professional journal has, you could try [this](http://www.pme-math.org/journal/pmetemplate03.tex).

Hopefully, one of the 2 templates will get you unstuck.

Comment: I was told that MMA has a "junior" journal for undergrads called [College Math Journal](http://www.maa.org/pubs/cmj.html). I'm aiming for that.

Comment: It sounds like the first link I mentioned above is what you want. Information on the College Math Journal and LaTeX is mentioned [here](http://www.maa.org/pubs/mm-guide.html). Scroll down to "Writing and Revising" and then check out the comments on LaTeX in the "Style and Format" section. One of the links is to the template mentioned above.

Comment: Could you provide a new link to the sample math article from Mathematics Magazine?

Comment: Looks like it was moved. To find where it's gone I hover the mouse over the link and find the file was mmartic.tex after which I search Google by filetype "mmartic filetype:tex" This will help anyone find the file if it moves in the future. For now, just click [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maa.org%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fpdf%2Fpubs%2Fmm_supplements%2Fmmartic.tex&ei=pgD2U4OPGNfboAS5nIK4Bg&usg=AFQjCNGduB0BxPYSoq1Cf1VGkQxcjJ7lcw&bvm=bv.73373277,d.cGU).

Comment: @DJP: I find your answer very helpful. I tried to find a latex template for an article intended for a professional journal. Would you be able to update the second link or show me a place to find such a template?

Comment: The second link still works. However, it doesn't compile until you comment out the line for the picture (\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{para01.eps}). My computer gave me a warning about an unsecure site.  The file is pmetemplate03.tex on [this page](http://www.pme-math.org/journal/). In general, though, if you know the professional journal that you like the look of and go to their website they usually have a basic LaTeX template you can work with.

Comment: @Bumblebee Sites where they have templates: [Elsevier](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions), or [Springer](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support) or [arXiv.org](https://arxiv.org/). arXiv.org just search for a mathematics paper and look for download (other formats) for the tex file.

Answer (score 12):

I imagine you'll get many answers to your question- here is my humble attempt.

- From the *Mathematical* point of view, the first thing I always remember is to think of equations and formulas as part of the sentence- they are not separate objects that stand alone on the page
- From the *typesetting* point of view, it's always good to try and allow LaTeX to do the heavy lifting and tedious tasks for you. When I say 'tedious' tasks, I mean things such as

  - automatic enumerations of environments
  - cross referencing that is updated automatically (after 2 compilations)
  - pagination- allow your figures and tables to `float`, and try to avoid manually specifying page breaks

When it comes to Mathematical typesetting, the first package you should explore is the `amsmath` package- once you're comfortable with it, and perhaps need additional enhancements, you can study the `mathtools` package, which supplements it.

Of course, one final detail is to keep your code as tidy as possible so that it can be read easily by you (and perhaps others) in the future.

I've included a very simple sample document below that I hope might get you started- happy TeXing!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=0cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % page settings
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides many mathematical environments & tools

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\title{MTH 251: Week 2 lab write up}
\author{C. M. Hughes}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\subsection*{Lab activity 1.2.4}
Find the difference quotient of $f(x)$ when $f(x)=x^3$.

We proceed as demonstrated in the lab manual; assuming that $h\ne 0$ 
we have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} & =  \frac{(x+h)^3-x^3}{h}   \\
                          & =  \frac{x^3+3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3 - x^3}{h}\\
                          & =  \frac{3x^2h+2xh^2+h^3}{h}\\
                          & =  \frac{h(3x^2+2xh+h^2)}{h}\\
                          & =  3x^2+2xh+h^2
\end{align*} 

\subsection*{Lab activity 2.3.4}
Use the definition of the derivative to find $f'(x)$ when $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

Using the definition of the derivative, we have
\begin{align*}
            f'(x)           &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(x+h)^{1/4}-x^{1/4}}{h}   \\
                            &=  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(x+h)^{1/4}-x^{1/4}}{h}\cdot \frac{((x+h)^{1/4}+x^{1/4})((x+h)^{1/2}+x^{1/2})}{((x+h)^{1/4}+x^{1/4})((x+h)^{1/2}+x^{1/2})}\\
                            &=  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(x+h)-x}{h((x+h)^{1/4}+x^{1/4})((x+h)^{1/2}+x^{1/2})}    \\  
                            &=  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{((x+h)^{1/4}+x^{1/4})((x+h)^{1/2}+x^{1/2})}   \\
                            &= \frac{1}{(x^{1/4}+x^{1/4})(x^{1/2}+x^{1/2})} \\
                            &=  \frac{1}{(2x^{1/4})(2x^{1/2})}  \\
                            &=  \frac{1}{4x^{3/4}}  \\
                            &=  \frac{1}{4}x^{-3/4}
\end{align*}
Note: the key observation here is that
\begin{align*}
    a^4-b^4 &= (a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2)   \\
        &= (a-b)(a+b)(a^2+b^2), 
\end{align*}
with 
\[
    a = (x+h)^{1/4}, \qquad b = x^{1/4},
\]
which allowed us to rationalize the denominator.

\end{document}
```