# Seeking guidelines of how to write a scientific (mathematics) article in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: article, miktex2.9

I have installed MiKTeX 2.9 and opened TeXworks and I almost have no ideas of how, if I want to write a scientific (mathematics) article, to start and what to type.

You can imagine this situation as if you only know high school algebra and one semester of calculus and someone gives you a graduate-level book about Riemann zeta function.

Of course, you could find some way through and become familiar with some concepts in that book but thorough understanding by only knowing those mentioned basics would be almost impossible.

I am facing similar difficulties, because I have never wrote a scientific (mathematics) article and I want to know how to do it in MiKTeX 2.9.

Can you type some general guidelines in your answer, about how to write such kind of an article?

Also, you can suppose that pictures (images) will not be a part of the article, if that simplifies the task of helping me.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  As I see it, this question is more about what to put in your article rather than the mechanics.  And as the mechanics (TeX and front end software making the entry of the article straightforward) is what this site is about, I'm afraid this question is off-topic.  It might be more appropriate on math.stackexchange.  (The American Math Society published a book "How to Write Mathematics" by four mathematicians known as excellent writers: https://bookstore.ams.org/hwm/ . A web search for the same phrase also returns some useful possibilities.)

Comment: @barbara beeton I guess his question is not about mathematics itself. He wants to know how to write math in Latex. Hence may be on-topic.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45466/tex-templates-for-mathematical-articles/45473#45473) is helpful. Also, Overleaf has various mathematical templates [here](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/math). Finally, you can get .tex files of math articles from arXiv. New papers are [here](https://arxiv.org/list/math/recent) click on `other` for .tex file.

Comment: @hesham -- You may be correct, but the statement isn't really clear to me.  Perhaps the OP can be more specific about which meaning is intended.  (I won't vote to close unless I'm really sure.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I basically wanted to be helped about how to start the overall process of writing, for example here, an article, in MiKTeX, by being given some guidelines which are enough general and can be applied in much various situations (outcomes).

Comment: @barbarabeeton it is not about what i could write but what should be typed so that there are no errors and non-consistencies

Comment: @Ante -- Thanks for the clarification.  In addition to the answers (which are good), for math specifically, refer to the `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsldoc`) and, for examples, `testmath` -- both the `.tex` source file and the pdf output are in the `amsmath` collection.

Answer (score 2):

In latex editor (TeXworks in your case), copy and paste the following [code](https://www.namsu.de/Extra/klassen/latex-article-template.html):

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{A Small \LaTeX{} Article Template\thanks{To your mother}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
%
\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
    Short introduction to subject of the paper \ldots 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Make it possible for all to write documents with \LaTeX{}!

\paragraph{Outline}
First we start with a little example of the article class, which is an 
important documentclass. But there would be other documentclasses like 
book \ref{book}, report \ref{report} and letter \ref{letter} which are 
described in Section \ref{documentclasses}. Finally, Section 
\ref{conclusions} gives the conclusions.
%
\section{Document classes} \label{documentclasses}

\begin{itemize}
    \item article
    \item book 
    \item report 
    \item letter 
\end{itemize}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item article
    \item book 
    \item report 
    \item letter 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
    \item[article\label{article}]{Article is \ldots}
    \item[book\label{book}]{The book class \ldots}
    \item[report\label{report}]{Report gives you \ldots}
    \item[letter\label{letter}]{If you want to write a letter.}
\end{description}


\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}
There is no longer \LaTeX{} example which was written by \cite{doe}.


\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem[Doe]{doe} \emph{First and last \LaTeX{} example.},
    John Doe 50 B.C. 
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Now compile your file (from run or build and view icon), you should get an output like this:

[image]
[image]

Which is mostly self explanatory. From here you can start expanding your knowledge add/modify by reading and searching about what you exactly want to do.

Comment: this seems very fine! thank you!

Comment: You may also check this very helpful answer in your case   for how to write mathematics equations https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45466/tex-templates-for-mathematical-articles

Comment: I personally like this answer a lot https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45474/91556